# How to fix the bug where viewDidScroll is called when UIViewController is already gone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I often got excbadaccess. Very rare. But sometimes it happens.

I tried zombie build and I got this:

```
*** -[BGDetailBusinessViewController scrollViewDidScroll:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x189f09c0
```

I suppose it happens due to the following

I pop out a BGDetailBusinessViewController while scrolling.

The view is still scrolling.

It sent notification somewhere to call it's delegate, namely the BGDetailBusinessViewController object. Because reference to delegate is weak, I suppose this what causes the problem.

Now, how exactly I can fix that?

The way weak reference work is if the object is deallocated it'll be nil right?

Perhaps it's not nil due to the zombie. However, that means this bug will show up if I build with zombie build.

If an object becomes zombie, will all weak reference to that object nilled?

In any case, I wonder how to fix this bug given that I have manage to found it.

Some says that I should set delegate to nil in dealloc.

[Are all weak references nilled if we enable zombie object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418648/are-all-weak-references-nilled-if-we-enable-zombie-object/20418858?noredirect=1#20418858) suggest otherwise. When an object is deallocated, all weak references, such delegate should have been nilled.

Actually I really couldn't think of any reason why, with zombie or not, accessing deallocated object can happen at all. If a reference is strong, then object is not deallocated. If reference is weak then it's nilled when object is deallocated.

Yet, the app did crash with error: message sent to deallocated instance 0x189f09c0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the delegate to nil in the dealloc method using

```
scrollView.delegate = nil;
```

A deallocated object is deallocated (and removed from memory) but not set to nil. You have to explicitly set it to nil.

Comment: I thought scrollView.delegate is a weak reference. I thought all weak references are automatically nilled when objects are deallocated?

Comment: Doing that for all scrollView will be pretty cumbersome don't you think?

Comment: your weak property inside your class may be nil, but the delegate property of the scroll view still points to the old address. Even if it sounds cumbersome, there is no alternative

Comment: @JimThio: The `delegate` property of `UIScrollView` is *not weak*! It is declared as `@property(nonatomic, assign)`, and "assign" is the same as "unsafe_unretained". So it is not nilled automatically.

Comment: What? Why iPhone decides to use assign? In what heaven name would anyone uses assign instead of weak? Martin you should set that as answre.

Comment: I guess Apple did not have time to rewrite all iOS code after the introduction of ARC...

Comment: @JimThio: You got already two answers that should solve your problem, there is no need to add another one.

Comment: Make sense. They do solve my problem. However, without your explanation I won't sleep. It's the insight that count.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to unsubscribe from scrollView 'notifications'?

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    self.scrollView.delegate = nil; // or tableView, collectionView, etc.
}
```