# Are all weak references nilled if we enable zombie object?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Normally, if an object deallocated, all weak references will be nilled.

What about if we enable zombie object?

Product -> Edit Scheme -> Enable Zombie Object

Will weak references be nilled too?

Otherwise, bugs that won't happen on normal circumstances will happen on enable zombie object

I strongly suspected, as one of the answer says, that weak references will be nilled.

That being said,

[How to fix the bug where viewDidScroll is called when UIViewController is already gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418572/how-to-fix-the-bug-where-viewdidscroll-is-called-when-uiviewcontroller-is-alread/20418621?noredirect=1#comment30496349_20418621) and answer there suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The weak reference will be set to `nil` even if you enable Zombie Objects.

I tested it like this:

```
id __weak o;
@autoreleasepool {
    id ob = [[NSObject alloc] init];
    o = ob;
    NSLog(@"Weak ref before release %@", o);
}
NSLog(@"Weak ref after release %@", o);
```

With Zombies enabled or not, the same output happens:

```
2013-12-05 23:55:35.571 WeakPointers[93840:303] Weak ref before release  
2013-12-05 23:55:35.572 WeakPointers[93840:303] Weak ref after release (null)
```

Comment: That's what I thought. Yet this bug, and all answers suggest otherwise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418572/how-to-fix-the-bug-where-viewdidscroll-is-called-when-uiviewcontroller-is-alread/20418621?noredirect=1#comment30496349_20418621

Comment: @JimThio: The `delegate` property of `UIScrollView` is not weak. It is declared as `@property(nonatomic, assign)`, and "assign" is the same as "unsafe_unretained". So it is not nilled automatically.