# Is there any way, deallocated object can be accessed if we never use assign pointer?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Actually I really couldn't think of **any reason** why, with zombie or not, accessing deallocated object can happen at all. If a reference is strong, then object is not deallocated. If reference is weak then it's nilled when object is deallocated.

I suppose it could happen if people use assign pointer. But doing so would be asking for trouble.

However, sometimes my app do crash with this message:

Yet, the app did crash with error: message sent to deallocated instance 0x189f09c0

I have no idea why.

What happen is a UIViewController is pop out of UINavigationController. Then it's viewDidScroll is about to be called.

But that's strange.

I enabled zombie. However, enabling zombie shouldn't have been the case. This answer clearly shows that all weak references are niled even when debugging with zomie

[Are all weak references nilled if we enable zombie object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20418648/are-all-weak-references-nilled-if-we-enable-zombie-object/20418858?noredirect=1#20418858)

So what's going on?

Comment: As I already commented to your previous questions: The delegate property of UIScrollView is **"assign", not "weak"**. So you have to set it to nil explicitly, as has been said in previous answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the deallocated instance and trace it's life circle (where and when it is retained and released), see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7402171/calayer-release-message-sent-to-deallocated-instance/12055114#12055114)

It really helps me a lot!